# mscoree.dll not loaded. a runtime error occurred during the loading of the com add-in on Outlook 2016

Tags: office365, ms-office, outlook-addin

I'm trying to enable the outlook (office 365 pro plus) custom plugin call EloAddinHttp, its related to DMS software. there was a error message when i click on it, 
"mscoree.dll not loaded. a runtime error occurred during the loading of the com add-in",

Load behavior also set as "3". But unable to Activate this add-in on outlook when i put tick and save its not saving on Outlook. This add-in is working on some PCs. Can anyone help me to find the issue why this working only on some PCs(All pcs have same office365 pro plus version).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest contacting add-in developers instead. Most probably the fires an exception at runtime while it is loaded/initialized. Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again.

Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2019) article.